# Odd behaviour of Python lists

Tags: python

Is it possible that when appending lists of function objects in `Python 3`, the order gets lost?

My understanding was that Python lists are ordered and indeed running

```
numbers = []

for i in range(10):

    numbers.append(i)

print(numbers)
```

returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` as expected.

If I append **function objects** however, like in this MWE:

```
functions = []

for k in range(10):

    def test():
        print('This is the %i th function.' %k)

    functions.append(test)
```

and call `functions[2]()` I get `This is the 9 th function.`

Can somebody make sense of this odd behaviour?

Comment: [Late Binding Closures](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function closure does not capture the value of a variable when it is defined, it captures the name of the variable.

Thus, the function you have stored in `functions[2]` references `k`.  When you call it, it will show you the value of `k` when it is called, not when it was defined.

Comment: Yup... and the fix is to use `def test(k=k)` to bind it appropriately...